# Regex in jquery for input type text

Tags: jquery, regex

I want 6 regular expressions in jquery for these following conditions.

1. Limit of the letters = 200 (max 431)
2. The maximum allowed same consecutive letters=5
3. If "space" is pressed,no more symbols to be accepted
4. The sign "-" is accepted,but only twice
5. The sign "." is accepted,but only twice
6. The sign "_" is accepted,but only twice

I need 6 separate regular expressions for these conditions.

Can you help me in developing these regular expressions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share your efforts !

Comment: `If "space" is pressed` would not be a PHP process. `I want 6 regular expressions` is not how SO works. Show us the code you are using and what your issues are and we'll help... or ask about some specific coding aspect and we can help with that. This is too broad as is.

Comment: ^(?:(\w)(?!\1\1\1\1))+$ i have used this but this is not allowing me to enter any special character like "-","_".

Comment: yes i know but I am confused whatever i am using is not working

Comment: Did you look at what `\w` is? http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html `\w stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII characters [A-Za-z0-9_].` The underscore is allowed, you'd need to provide an example of how that is failing you.

Comment: Now i have these two regex 
1) ^(?!.*[._]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$
2) ^(?:(\w)(?!\1\1\1\1))+$
first one is not allowing me to add any 2 "-","_","."
second one not allow more than 5 consecutive characters but it also not allow to add any special character

Comment: Why 6? What is the sample string you are running against?

Comment: I have a textbox and i need if user type consecutive 5 letters then message should be shown to him like "abvvvvvv" or if he types "ab.c.." or "a_b__" or "a-bc--"

Answer (score 0):

Limit of the letters = 200 (max 431)

```
/(\w.*){201}/
```

The maximum allowed same consecutive letters=5

```
/(\w)(\1){4}/
```

If "space" is pressed,no more symbols to be accepted

```
/ ./
```

The sign "-" is accepted,but only twice

```
/(-.*){3}/
```

The sign "." is accepted,but only twice

```
/(\..*){3}/
```

The sign "_" is accepted,but only twice

```
/(_.*){3}/
```

Comment: this isn't working

Comment: For each of these you need to negate the match `if(!preg_match(...))`. If you can't get it working make sure you understand what each regex is doing and check your implementation.